# Using def_delegate with a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know how Forwardable#def_delegate works with methods on objects, but is there a similar way to forward methods names to hash keys. Like:

```
hash = { some_value: 42, other_value: 31415 }
def_delegate :hash, :some_value, :other_value
```

Calling `object.some_value` should return `42`

PS: def and class eval is a way, but is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good job for [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html), which basically wraps a Hash in an object.

```
2.2.1 :001 > require 'ostruct'
 => true
2.2.1 :002 > s = OpenStruct.new(a: 1, b: 2)
 => #<OpenStruct a=1, b=2>
2.2.1 :003 > s.a
 => 1
2.2.1 :004 > s.c = 3
 => 3
```

If you want to be strict about the methods available, [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html) lets you create little, dynamic classes.

```
2.2.1 :001 > hash = {a: 1, b: 2}
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
2.2.1 :002 > struct = Struct.new(*hash.keys)
 => #<Class:0x007fd104b32888>
2.2.1 :003 > instance = struct.new(*hash.values)
 => #<struct a=1, b=2>
2.2.1 :004 > instance.a = 3
 => 3
2.2.1 :005 > instance.c
NoMethodError: undefined method `c' for #<struct a=3, b=2>
```

Answer (score 8):

Not directly, no. One option is to use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) from Ruby's standard library.

```
require "ostruct"

class Foo
  extend Forwardable
  delegate :@data, :some_value, :other_value

  def initialize(hash)
    @data = OpenStruct.new(hash)
  end
end

hash = { some_value: 42, other_value: 31415 }
foo = Foo.new(hash)
foo.some_value # => 42
```

A simpler option is to just delegate the `:[]` method, but it's not as pretty:

```
class Foo
  extend Forwardable
  delegate :@data, :[]

  def initialize(hash)
    @data = hash
  end
end

hash = { some_value: 42, other_value: 31415 }
foo = Foo.new(hash)
foo[:some_value] # => 42
```

Barring that, there's always `define_method`:

```
[ :some_value, :other_value ].each do |meth|
  define_method(meth) { @data[meth] }
end
```

Or `method_missing`:

```
def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
  return @data[meth] if @data.key?(meth)
  super
end

def respond_to_missing?(meth, *args)
  @data.key?(meth) || super
end
```

Comment: The `method_missing` option is the best, as OpenStruct returns nil if you call an existent method, which can lead to all sorts of troubles. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to implement this probably won't involve `Forwardable`, and  will depend on your specific use case. Here is an example of one way you could do this without eval:

```
class C
  class << self
    attr_accessor :hash

    def def_hash_delegate(key)
      define_method(key) do
        C.hash[key]
      end
    end
  end

  @hash = { some_value: 42, other_value: 31415 }

  def_hash_delegate :some_value
  def_hash_delegate :other_value
  def_hash_delegate :value_3
end

c = C.new

puts c.some_value
puts c.other_value
C.hash[:value_3] = 3948
puts c.value_3
```

Comment: is a good solution I have now something similar but I was looking for simpler ways, @Kristján solution looks nice

Comment: I did something similar to this but based it on Rails `delegate to:` DSL as I think it is more intuitive than `def_delegators` - https://gist.github.com/eric-hemasystems/f66777bc46879bd8ba6df42751089ae3